# How to place my functions in similar lines?

Tags: c

The code below shows the factors of the number being input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void factorer(int x);
void factorer2(int x);

int main()
{
  int number;
  printf("Find factors of: ");
  scanf("%d", &number );
}
  
void factorer(int x)
{
  int number;
  int dividend;

  dividend = x;

  for (number = 1; number <= x; number++) {
    if(dividend % number == 0) {
      printf("%d\n", number);
    }
  }
}

void factorer2(int x)
{
  int number;
  int dividend;

  dividend = x;

  for (number = x; number > 0; number--) {
    if (dividend % number == 0) {
      printf("%d\n", number);
    }
  }
}
```

example if 10 is the input number, the output would be

```
1
2
5
10
10
5
2
1
```

but the output that i want is something that goes like

```
1 x 10
2 x 5
5 x 2
10 x 1
```

I know calling `void` functions are not possible in `printf()` so how might I be able to make this possible?

### update:

I have tried sir @gene's code, but the output would show something like:

```
1 x 0
2 x 0
5 x 0
10 x 1
```

not the output that i wanted

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
printf(" %d x %d \n",dividend,number/dividend);
```

Comment: sir using the number/dividend makes the output to: 1 x 0, 2 x 0, 5 x 0, 10 x 1

Answer (score 2):

It takes practice to learn how to decompose algorithms into functions. Here it's not really necessary because the problem is quite simple.

```
int main (void) {
  int number;
  printf("Find factors of: ");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    if (number % i == 0)
      printf("%d x %d\n", i, number / i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had a feeling two functions were not needed.  A good puzzle for **codegolf**

Comment: yes sir thank you for the answer, but professor requires the use of functions

Comment: and sir @Gene 
the output of ur code becomes 
1 x 0,
2 x 0,
5 x 0,
10 x ,1

Comment: Runs fine on my machine. Did you include stdio.h?